# I have multiple profiles using profile 2 per user need to create view showing data from 2 profiles but only one line per user

Tags: users, views

Ok, I am creating a website for a volunteer agency which will have each member of the agency having their own log in to our site and a set of profiles made based upon important key data based upon the specific profile within their user acct.

The Profiles I have so far are

User - Default USER profile in Drupal

Roster Information (Roster)
Training Information (Training)
Driving Certifications Information (Driver)

What I am needing is to create a view that shows the following

User Name (User)  | ID # (Roster) | Name (Roster) | Truck 1 (Driver)| Truck 2 (Driver)

with one line per user what I am getting is

Username (User) | ID # (Roster) | Name (Roster) 
Username (User) |                                 | Truck 1 (Driver)| Truck 2 (Driver)

Can someone assist in creating this view in such a way as each user has only one line based upon the PID located within the Profiles2 data for the 2 profiles referenced and linked with the users UID under the default drupal profile?

Comment: see image example at http://kovudalion.com/exampleview.jpg Need each user to only have one line and all items to show INLINE

Comment: Found answer 

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58384/using-profile2-and-views-how-to-display-the-separate-profile-data-on-a-single